# one-liner for exit with message in capistrano

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

It is possible to have a one liner condition for exit with message?

```
if condition
  info "some message"
  exit
end
```

Comment: `condition && info("exiting") && exit`.

Comment: Or you could put info "some message" and exit into a function, then do function if condition.

Comment: This is what i need sir @AlekseiMatiushkin, Thank you

Comment: @TedTran2019 or simply `(info("exiting") && exit) if condition`. The dedicated function looks a bit of overhead here.

Answer (score 0):

To exit from Capistrano in a 1 line and including the message you can do something like this

`(info("Your message here ... ") && exit) if condition`

I hope that this will help